# Is it possible to make a binding in a menu control using list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I made a style for my menu control and now I want to use that style for all the menuItems, but with different text in the textbox. I was wondering if I can use a List to populate the binding element...I tried but it doesnt work...Have I missed something or I have to use something else?

```
  List<string> itemArray = new List<string>();
        itemArray.Add("label1");
        itemArray.Add("label2");
        itemArray.Add("label3");
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("itemArray");

       this.menu1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

and the one part of the style is, if it helps...:

```
 <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid>
            <Border Name="MainBorder" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0" >
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=itemArray}" Margin="30,10,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <Image Width="15" Height="15" Source="image.PNG" Margin="-100,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

Comment: See the Remarks section in the MSDN doc on [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.aspx) to get an overview of its HeaderedItemsControl features and how to use data binding with MenuItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to bind a text element to a `List<T>`, which will result in the type name. If you want the menu to populate itself from a list of objects, consider binding the menu's `ItemsSource` property to that list:

```
     <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}">
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding Command}" />
           </DataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
     </Menu>
```

In this example, each list item is an object with a `Text` property which shows up as the display string, and a `Command` property, which is an object that implements [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx). When the user chooses a menu item, that list item's `Command.Execute` method is invoked; you could use something like [`RelayCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) or [`ReactiveCommand`](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/06/22/reactivexaml-series-reactivecommand/) to turn that into a method call.

This allows for a flat menu; for a hierarchical menu you'll have to do something a little different.